# DelegateCommand throws 'specified cast is not valid' for WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this) for opening a file browser

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui-3

**ViewModel class**

```
        public ICommand OpenFileDialog { get; set; }
        private string configFile;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.OpenFileDialog = new DelegateCommand(browseFileButton_Click, OnMyCommandCanExecute);

        }

        public string ConfigFile
        {
            get
            {
                return configFile;
            }
            set
            {
                configFile = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private async void browseFileButton_Click(object sender)
        {
            var filePicker = new FileOpenPicker()
            {
                FileTypeFilter = { ".pdf" },
                ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail
            };
            var hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
            InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(filePicker, hWnd);

            var file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            if (file != null)
            {
                ConfigFile = file.Name;
            }
        }

        private bool OnMyCommandCanExecute(object obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

I have the ViewModel with a simple view with the code above tied to a button to open a file browser using FileOpenPicker. The result of the chosen file is bound to the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because when you call,

```cs
var hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
```

`this` is type of `MainViewModel` but `GetWindowHandle()` requires type of `Window`.

You should consider do this open file process in the code behind of a `Page` or the `MainWindow`.

Comment: I was actually able to add a command parameter to the button to provide the method in the view model with the window which is then used like,

private async void OpenFileDialog_Click(Window window)
{
   var hWnd = WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
}

which also works

Comment: This is just an opinion but try to keep UI specific stuff in the View. It's cleaner and more maintanble that way. But also agree with the idea of what works, works.

Comment: I actually meant to comment back after that one, but I agree. For the sake of separating the UI interactions from the logic for the rest of the app, I decided I would move some things around and make it a bit easier on myself. Thanks.